# Windows domain, sessions by user

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain

On a Windows domain, given a user name, how do you get a list of machines that the user is currently logged onto (via RDP)?

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

At least not if you don't properly define "logged onto" (RDP? Local console? File share? Printer? Web site? DB?).

And even then, it's quite a difficult task, as there is no central repository for this information; you have to either scan each machine for active sessions or query the security logs on all domain controllers.

There are third-party auditing tools that can track this, but there is no easy built-in way in AD to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We do this the 'easy' way, with logon/logoff scripts, either writing machine name, username and time to a SQL database or file on a 'hidden' AUDIT$ share that Everyone can modify, or changing the Description to the username (used to look good in WinXP Explorer's view of the domain).

It *may* be even easier to do set the Description, now, with Group Policy Preferences, i.e. 
adding a user preference to replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters\srvcomment` to be a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` with value `%USERNAME%`.  It would only work for the last logged-in user though and would probably only be partial for multi-user (e.g. Remote Desktop, Fast User Switching) setups.

Of course, if you are looking for a holistic outside-in approach, you have to examine the Event Logs on each computer -- perhaps with Powershell's `Get-EventLog` cmdlet.  There was a pretty good blog post with what you would need to look for at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, there is no central database of who is logged in where, etc. However, if you're only concerned with a certain subset of machines, or you can at least enumerate them, then you can use PowerShell to query them to see who is connected.